# Deprecated API usage UIWebView in FBSDKCoreKit iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

In the past days Apple was sending a warning in email each time a new build was uploaded to Appstore Connect containing the following message:

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

The problem is that the only component using UIWebView in our app is the FBSDKCoreKit iOS framework. I updated to the latest version, but they didn't replace it yet with WKWebView.

Does anybody know when they are planning to release a new update having the fix for this issue?

Comment: I don't get why they would downvote this